# How to make UIView with AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer look better?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, avfoundation, calayer

I'm trying to build a subclass of UIView to quickly take one snapshot by using AVFoundation.
It's working great but I would really like to make the corners round or add a little shadow.
How can I achieve this using Core Graphics etc.?

GitHub: https://github.com/dariolass/QuickShotView

**Update:** This is what the result looks like:

http://www.bytolution.com/qsv.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use QuartzCore

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

then you can modify the layer off your the view:

```
someView.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
someView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-15, 20);
someView.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
someView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
```

or something like that